# Strange makefile behaviour in gmake 4.0

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am facing some strange changes in behaviour between gmake 3.8 and gmake 4.0. This is observed on the same machine, running Windows 7. The following is a much simplified example - it is obviously not a useful makefile, but illustrates the issue.

make -v output for 3.8 identifies as:

> GNU Make 3.80

and 4.0 as:

> GNU Make 4.0
>
> Built for Windows32

The "Built for Windows32" is missing from the 3.8 output, but I assume this was added after the 3.8 release.

Consider the following directory structure:

```
.
./Build
./PROJ1
./PROJ1/Makefile
```

And following makefile in PROJ1:

```
.PHONY: build clean    

build:
    @echo Build Recipe

clean:
    @echo Clean Recipe
```

This makefile is run from the parent directory eg:
`make -C PROJ1 build`.
In gmake 3.8, this does the expected thing of printing `Build Recipe`:

```
make: Entering Directory PROJ1
Build Recipe
make: Exiting Directory PROJ1
```

However, the same makefile in gmake 4.0 does something unexpected:

```
make -C PROJ1 build
make: Entering directory 'PROJ1'
make: *** No rule to make target 'Build'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory 'PROJ1'
```

Strange. For some reason it is trying to make 'Build' rather than 'build'. Now, if we try to make clean, then in both 3.8 and 4.0 we get the following:

```
testmake>make -C PROJ1 clean
make: Entering directory 'PROJ1'
Clean Recipe
make: Leaving directory 'PROJ1'
```

Which is the desired behaviour. One thing i noticed is that this affects every target where there is a directory with a name differing only by case - and we can demonstrate this by creating a directory "Clean":

```
.
./Build
./Clean
./PROJ1
./PROJ1/Makefile

make -C PROJ1 clean
make: Entering directory 'PROJ1'
make: *** No rule to make target 'Clean'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory 'PROJ1'
```

What is going on, and how can I resolve this?

Interestingly, gmake 4.2.1 running in cygwin does *not* exhibit the crazy behaviour - it correctly executes the build or clean recipe as requested.

Comment: works here as expected with 4.1 and 4.2.1.  Perhaps some other parts of the system (bash-completion?) try to fix spelling of cli parameters.  Try with `strace -f -eexecve make -C PROJ1 build` to see what  is really executed.

Comment: By any coincidence, are you working on Windows?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes, this is on Windows 7.

Comment: Then I think that maybe the target to file name resolution was somehow changed. The best thing I think is to try the most recent version of GNUmake. Can you run the build process in a Cygwin environment?

Comment: Using gmake 4.2.1 in cygwin does the correct thing - builds what I asked for.

Comment: GNU make can be compiled with case insensitive file naming enabled, or disabled.  Probably one binary you have has case-insensitive file system support enabled, and one binary has it disabled.  It looks like there may also be an issue with dealing with case-insensitive filesystems, in some situations.

Comment: The strange thing is that the Build folder is in the directory I invoked make from, not the directory specified by the -C option.